# On a certain OEIS convention

Tags: oeis

Do you know what it is that those numbers which appear in the upper-right angle of the blue-box mean?

[image]

I presume they have to do with a certain ranking of the sequences within the site, but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: It seems to me that the meaning of those numbers is nowhere to be found in the FAQ for the OEIS.

Comment: Neil Sloane [sent out an email today](http://list.seqfan.eu/pipermail/seqfan/2018-February/018306.html) saying there is a bug in ranking algorithm of the new version of the OEIS. This probably explains why the number you're seeing is so funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [OEIS hints page](http://oeis.org/hints.html):

> **The meaning of the little numbers at the right of the blue bar.** For example, +30 and 1086 for A000045.
>
> The +30 is the sequence's query score -- how well it matches the query.
>
> You get 100 points for matching ordering (for example, having 1 3 5 not 1 2 3 4 5 when the query is 1 3 5).
>
> You get 10 points for matching terms in certain lines (for example, sequence data counts more, and sequence number counts a lot more).
>
> The 1086 is the number of sequences in the database that reference the given sequence.
>
> The "relevance" sort is by query score, with ties broken by reference count.